# Error when trying to execute action class after hosting a java website made in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, localhost, hosting

I have made a website in java struts2 and i have hosted it.
Its running well but what happens is whenever i try to execute any action it gives error of 404 . when i run on any local server through eclipse everything is fine ,no error and no exceptions but after hosting it gives this error.
when i run on local host its URL is ёhttp://localhost:8280/foryou/searchonbb.actionё and everything works perfectly.
and when i try to execute same action online its shows URL something like this http://info4blood.in/foryou/foryou/BloodBankSection.jsp#login and error image is attached . what i found is when i deployed app in Cpanel all java classes are placed in WEB-INF folder with .class files as well. So is this the problem ?? But i am able to login in to an account and after login into any account and when try to execute some action i face problem.
**Note: while uploading my web app i set contextpath to "foryou".**
Anybody please help . Thanks in advance :)[image: Error]

Comment: i read one solution of renaming my war to ROOT.war but in my cpanel i already have a root.war and it has some tomcat files ? so what can i do ?

Comment: You have to read the log file (probably cpanel has a link to it), logs file have the answer ;)

Comment: it gives this error : [Tue Aug 18 15:13:31.960847 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 9158:tid 139891826427648] [client 70.39.187.31:40831] AH02812: attempt to invoke directory as script: /home/info4blood/public_html/cgi-bin/, referer: http://info4blood.in/

Comment: what should be done so ?

Comment: There isn't enough info to know whats happening. There's double "foryou" in the url, is that correct?

Comment: yes thats what i am asking why is it so ? i think that is only the problem but  can anybody help me out :(

Comment: i am not able to execute any java action except logging into an account ..it shows 404 error and some link like which i posted above . i hope i am clear now.

Comment: remove the context, simply get it working on your local for `/` context and then upload it with name `ROOT.war`. Feel free to rename the existing `ROOT.war` after stopping tomcat.

Comment: As a rule of convention, avoid to make `.jsp` requests if you're using struts2, every URL should be that of an action, although it can be only a namesake action.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, it's a context problem.

1. Fix your code such that is works for root context (`/`) locally i.e. `http://localhost:8280/foryou/searchonbb.action` will become
   `http://localhost:8280/searchonbb.action`
2. Upload on server with name `ROOT.war` (case is important)
3. If there is existing `ROOT.war` on server, simply stop tomcat and rename it and then upload your `ROOT.war`

Comment: there is already a root folder in my web apps under tomcat folder in cpanel so i should rename that? will it affect anything because it has some images and files of tomcat . should i post a image?

Comment: Most of the time it's useless but still we're just renaming it and can rollback if any problem occurs.

Comment: okay let me try. so what i will do is first of all stop tomcat ,rename existing root folder in cpanel and then upload a new war file with ROOT name and deploy it ? is there anything else to be done ?

Comment: first step : make sure the app works with `/` context in your local setup before uploading it.

Comment: okay i will try and let you know sir . BTW thanks a lot sir :)

Comment: its working in localhost with context "/" as u said ..so should i change it while uploading war file ?

Comment: is not working when i rename an existing ROOT folder in Cpanel and uploading my app as ROOT.war . is there any other solution ?

Comment: what is the context you set while uploading ? Try `{blank}` and `/`

Comment: Both doesnt work ,blank is not allowed and  i have tried using "/" but still the same problem. :(

Comment: how can i set blank in context

Comment: try `ROOT`, if that also doesn't work, I'm afraid you'll have to ask the hosting support

Comment: i tried with root but doesnt work . yeah  i will have to contact them only

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

In eclipse (right click on my project) under properties > web project settings > set context path to **"/"** and now make WAR file of your project .
Upload project in NGASI panel **(hosting panel provided by webhosting providers)** and deploy your project and after deploying **(it will ask you to set context path)** set context path in ngasi panel to "**foryou**" which is my project name and deployed it .and it worked perfectly !